# iAd enabled app not receiving any requests

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, iad

The last iAd enabled app I released started generating requests almost immediately as soon as it appeared in the app store, but did not generate any impressions for 3-4 days until it started receiving ads from Apple (that behavior is normal)

Yesterday I released an iAd enabled app and it has not generated a single request let alone impression.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barograph/id926055907?mt=8

The app is NOT listed as for kids.
The app does successfully generate test ads when I was running my beta builds before submitting it.
The apps shows up in my iAd.apple.com dashboard normally with a green light and it says it is recieving ads, but it has not generated a single request yet.
My contracts in ITC are up to date.

Is there anything I might have done wrong, or anything I have forgotten to do which would be preventing me from getting any ad requests?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, this appears to be normal. Even though some apps generate requests immediately, others take a few days (in both cases it takes a few days to generate actual impressions). My latest app started receiving requests just over 24 hours after the release date and started generating impressions at the same time. The dapp before that started generating requests immediately but did not get any impressions for 3-4 days.